# MySQL select rows which not having specific value in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Tables:

```
   users (id, name)
   permissions (id, area_id, user_id)
```

I want to select all users which do not have area_id lets say 5 in permissions table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a left join between the tables, putting a check for the relevant area_id in the ON clause (hence if no matching records the left table row is still brought back), but then in the WHERE clause check there was no matching record.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM users a
LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions b
ON a.id = b.user_id
AND b.area_id = 5
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me! Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT user.* FROM USER 
INNER JOIN permissions ON 
(user.id=permissions.user_id AND permissions.area_id=0)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Not all users have permissions at all